# Query equipos con contratos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dos queries, las cuales en una muestran los contratos y maquinas asociados a estos los cuales estan en estado vencido del mes anterior y la otra muestra todos los contratos que estan en estado vigentes. Estos alimentan dos reportes por si mismos.

**Vencidos:**

```
SELECT
    t2.Codigo as Cod_cliente,
    t3.Numero as Contrato,
    t3.Estado,
    t3.Fecha_inicio,
    t3.Fecha_termino,
    t4.Serie AS Equipo
FROM Compania AS t1
LEFT JOIN Clientes AS t2
    ON LTRIM(t2.RUT) = t1.RUT
LEFT JOIN Contratos as t3
    ON t3.Codigo_cliente = t2.Codigo
LEFT JOIN Equipos as t4
    ON t3.Serie = t4.Serie
WHERE t2.Codigo IS NOT NULL
    AND t3.Estado = 'Vencido'
    AND YEAR(t3.Fecha_termino) = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))
    AND MONTH(t3.Fecha_termino) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))
ORDER BY t3.Fecha_termino DESC
```

| Cod_cliente | Contrato | Estado | Fecha_inicio | Fecha_termino | Equipo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 223374 | 4758115-40 | Vencido | 2019-06-27 | 2022-06-26 | CX4576 |
| 223374 | 4758115-60 | Vencido | 2019-06-27 | 2022-06-26 | MZ1156 |
| 347636 | 1150008 | Vencido | 2021-06-13 | 2022-06-12 | II7894 |
| 165881 | 6077852 | Vencido | 2021-06-15 | 2022-06-14 | IZ4555 |

**Vigentes:**

```
SELECT
    t2.Codigo as Cod_cliente,
    t3.Numero as Contrato,
    t3.Estado,
    t3.Fecha_inicio,
    t3.Fecha_termino,
    t4.Serie AS Equipo
FROM Compania AS t1
LEFT JOIN Clientes AS t2
    ON LTRIM(t2.RUT) = t1.RUT
LEFT JOIN Contratos as t3
    ON t3.Codigo_cliente = t2.Codigo
LEFT JOIN Equipos as t4
    ON t3.Serie = t4.Serie
WHERE t2.Codigo IS NOT NULL
    AND t3.Estado = 'Vigente'
ORDER BY t3.Fecha_termino DESC
```

| Cod_cliente | Contrato | Estado | Fecha_inicio | Fecha_termino | Equipo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 950492 | 2334543 | Vigente | 2022-05-31 | 2023-02-03 | AP3345 |
| 347971 | 667832-01 | Vigente | 2022-04-30 | 2023-02-03 | ZC3116 |
| 347636 | 1150008 | Vigente | 2022-04-04 | 2023-01-15 | II7894 |
| 165881 | 6077852 | Vigente | 2021-02-15 | 2023-01-03 | BA3006 |

El asunto, es que ahora me estan pidiendo un nuevo reporte, el cual indique que equipos que estaban en un contrato que venció, no están ahora en otro contrato vigente... El detalle es que he tratado de hacer alguna querie con whith para poder unir las dos queries y luego filtrar, pero no he logrado nada aun...

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Actualizacion:

Trate algo asi, pero no me funciono

```
    WITH Expirados AS (
        SELECT
            t2.Codigo as Cod_cliente,
        t3.Numero as Contrato,
        t3.Estado,
        t3.Fecha_inicio,
        t3.Fecha_termino,
        t4.Serie AS Equipo
        FROM Compania AS t1
        LEFT JOIN Clientes AS t2
        ON LTRIM(t2.RUT) = t1.RUT
        LEFT JOIN Contratos as t3
        ON t3.Codigo_cliente = t2.Codigo
        LEFT JOIN Equipos as t4
        ON t3.Serie = t4.Serie
        WHERE t2.Codigo IS NOT NULL
        AND t3.Estado = 'Vencido'
        AND YEAR(t3.Fecha_termino) = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))
        AND MONTH(t3.Fecha_termino) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))
    ),
    Vigentes AS (
        SELECT
        t2.Codigo as Cod_cliente,
        t3.Numero as Contrato,
        t3.Estado,
        t3.Fecha_inicio,
        t3.Fecha_termino,
        t4.Serie AS Equipo
        FROM Compania AS t1
        LEFT JOIN Clientes AS t2
        ON LTRIM(t2.RUT) = t1.RUT
        LEFT JOIN Contratos as t3
        ON t3.Codigo_cliente = t2.Codigo
        LEFT JOIN Equipos as t4
        ON t3.Serie = t4.Serie
        WHERE t2.Codigo IS NOT NULL
        AND t3.Estado = 'Vigente'
    )
        
    SELECT *
FROM Expirados
WHERE Maquina NOT IN (
    SELECT Maquina FROM Vigentes
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según entendí el único ID que debería de no aparecer sería el Equipo II7894, ya que, todos los demás no aparecen en la tabla Vigentes. De tal modo que puedes usar CTE's - tal como haz estado planteando - y la cláusula ANY.

#### Uso de CTE's:

```sql
    WITH Expirados AS (
        SELECT
            t2.Codigo as Cod_cliente,
        t3.Numero as Contrato,
        t3.Estado,
        t3.Fecha_inicio,
        t3.Fecha_termino,
        t4.Serie AS Equipo
        FROM Compania AS t1
        LEFT JOIN Clientes AS t2
        ON LTRIM(t2.RUT) = t1.RUT
        LEFT JOIN Contratos as t3
        ON t3.Codigo_cliente = t2.Codigo
        LEFT JOIN Equipos as t4
        ON t3.Serie = t4.Serie
        WHERE t2.Codigo IS NOT NULL
        AND t3.Estado = 'Vencido'
        AND YEAR(t3.Fecha_termino) = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))
        AND MONTH(t3.Fecha_termino) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))
    ),
    Vigentes AS (
        SELECT
        t2.Codigo as Cod_cliente,
        t3.Numero as Contrato,
        t3.Estado,
        t3.Fecha_inicio,
        t3.Fecha_termino,
        t4.Serie AS Equipo
        FROM Compania AS t1
        LEFT JOIN Clientes AS t2
        ON LTRIM(t2.RUT) = t1.RUT
        LEFT JOIN Contratos as t3
        ON t3.Codigo_cliente = t2.Codigo
        LEFT JOIN Equipos as t4
        ON t3.Serie = t4.Serie
        WHERE t2.Codigo IS NOT NULL
        AND t3.Estado = 'Vigente'
    )
```

#### Consulta final con ANY:

```sql
SELECT E.*
FROM Expirados E
WHERE NOT E.Equipo = ANY (SELECT V.Equipo
                          FROM Vigentes V)
```

#### Consulta final con EXCEPT:

```sql
SELECT E.Equipo
FROM Expirados E
EXCEPT
SELECT V.Equipo
FROM Vigentes V
```

> Al final también se me ocurrió que puedes usar EXCEPT. Recuerda que siempre el EXCEPT y el NOT IN serán mucho más recomendables que usar LEFT JOIN, por la performance.

---

#### EDIT:

Esto modifica en la consulta final:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM vencidos
WHERE equipo NOT IN (SELECT equipo 
                     FROM vigentes) 
      AND cliente IN (SELECT cliente 
                  FROM vigentes)
```

> Aclaro, esto puede ser modificado para mejor performance. Lo dejo a libre criterio.

Comment: de momento me ha funcionado, pero tengo unos detalles aun. Que me aparecen `Equipos` en el resultado de Expirados de compañias que ya no aparecen en el listado de Vigentes. Ejemplo: `Compañia A tenia 3 equipos el cual tiene contratos expirados, pero en la tabla de Vigentes, esa compañia ya no existe`... La idea en general es revisar que equiposque estaban en un contrato que venció, no están ahora en otro contrato vigente, esto para comprobar cuales equipos no estan generando ingresos

Comment: Con el `ANY` debería ser suficiente, ¿puedes colocar un DBFiddle o algún ejemplo demostrable del output que te sale y del que quieres que te salga?

Comment: Te dejo un enlace de ina imagen de ejemplo de los resultados que obtengo y de lo que quiero obtener.
En la imagen, si te fijas, hay una compañia `Claudia Jessica...` que aparece en la tabla de Expirados, pero no en la tabla de vigentes, entonces el resultado que me debe entregar la query, debe excluir a todas las compañias que no esten en la tabla de Vigentes, no se si entiende:

https://ibb.co/fpqQbSZ

Comment: Lo acabo de editar, con eso ya te daría la respuesta que esperas.

Comment: muchas gracias!!! Ahora funciona perfectamente!
Primera vez que toco `ANY` en SQL Server, me queda harto por aprender.